# docker-compose.yml: services.environment must be a mapping when running command docker-compose up

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, yaml

I'm trying to run multiple instance of a mongodb via docker. When I use the command docker-compose up I get an error saying that services.environment must be a mapping. I've looked all around the web but everyone only talks about whitespace and I'm relatively sure my whitespace is not the problem. The following is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
# REST API running on Node JS container
  app:
    container_name: lafs-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  # link this container to the Mongo DB container
  links:
      - mongo
  # pass in environment variables for database host and name
  environment:
    - DB_HOST=mongodb
    - DB_NAME=lafs-db
  # Mongo DB storage container
  mongo:
    container_name: lafs-db
    image: 'mongo:4'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  # Attach the external network to these containers
  networks:
    default:
      external:
        name: lafs-net
```

The contents of the file were given to me by my instructor and should work but I'm not sure if it's not connecting to my DB or what but I should note that this course is several years old and a lot of it is deprecated.

I've tried changing the DB_HOST to localhost:27017 where the DB is but to no avail.

Comment: Whatever you've defined under `environment` does not look like a valid service

Comment: And if you write 'link this container', you should put that linking parts to the section **of that container**